# Orchard CMS - Custom Theme, Creating sections, one with second Navigation

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a custom theme, the footer, header & home page are all working.

I have a main navigation that links to 5 pages.

I now need to set the style for these 5 pages - and the other pages that link from them (it's different to the home page) - one section of which needs an additional navigation menu on the left (main nav is top).

Would I do this in Visual Studio - or can it be done through the admin web interface?

What is the best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an additional navigation widget on a layer that is not the homepage. As for styling differently on different pages, you could do that many ways.

For example, you could check if the page you are loading is the homepage and load some styles to overwrite the default ones. That would be the easy way I suppose.

If you need a whole new layout for the homepage, you could check out this module on the gallery which lets you select a different layout to use for each content item. Never used it myself, but looks like it could be cool :) http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Downplay.Orchard.LayoutSelector

Comment: Thanks.

Just styling the home page differently would be awkward - as it's total structure is different. I need to display different markup - then on other pages 1 of around 3 variations of layout.

Comment: Then you could try the module suggested above, that would probably be best. Or you could check the url in your layout and change the markup it creates, but this would get messy. Pretty quick.

Comment: could this be done in visual studio instead? Maybe that would be easier? (I would like to restrict the ability of the client to choose the wrong layout for the wrong page etc)

Comment: I found this article about creating new template files - based on pages identified clicking through site with designer tools: http://www.sarasota.me/blog/customizing-orchard-themes-using-shape-tracing-and-url-alternates-in-designer-tools